# ASP .NET Core 3 MVC Connection string issues on deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-express, .net-core-3.0, ef-core-3.0

**The scenario**

I'm creating an app and hosting it on Windows Server 2012. When developing, localdb works fine with the following Connection string:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DatabaseConnection": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDBFilename=[DataDirectory]\\<database name>.mdf;Integrated Security=True;"
  }
```

where [DataDirectory] is set in Startup.cs:

```
    var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(path, @"..\..\..\wwwroot\<folder name>"));
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", path);
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection").Replace("[DataDirectory]", path)));
```

Testing this on my local machine yields to the expected result.

**The problem**

Upon publishing it to server (the .mdf and the _log.ldf files are located in a folder under wwwroot and they are pusblished too), it is not working anymore:

*Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.
Development Mode
Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.
The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications. It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users. For local debugging, enable the Development environment by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development and restarting the app.*

I set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to *Development* and re-pusblished the app, but this is still the only error message I get, no details.

**Possible solution**

According to my research, it is not recommended to use *AttachDBFilename* in production and best would be to set up an SQL DB on the hosting machine. Don't want to get into details, even the idea of using a free version of SQL DB (Express) was refused, even though that would make solving the problem somewhat easier I guess (adjusting the Connection string).
This means I have to go with this *AttachDBFilename* workaround, even if it is not ideal.

(Have tried to modify the Connection string in many different ways but no luck. I also added the tag *Initial Catalog=(database name)*, and even though it is working on local, on remote it makes no change).

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.